# Make an iPhone app that sends text file, windows friendly (CRLF)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, newline

I am making an app that can create and email a text file. I would like to provide an option to send it in windows friendly or not.

How would you go about implementing windows friendly and mac friendly version.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a "normal" format -- CR or CRLF. When the user chooses the other format, filter the text file to replace the CR with CRLF or vice versa. You should be able to accomplish this easily using NSMutableString's -replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range: method or similar.